# NoReverseMatch error in django app

Tags: django, django-templates

I am receiving this error in one of my templates and cant seem to figure out what's wrong.

```
`NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'getimagefile' 
with arguments '(12L, 'afN9LRzESh4I9CGe6tFVoA==\n')' and 
keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My urls.py contains:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myproj.myapp.views',
url(r'^getimage/(?P<extractedcontent_id>\d+)/(?P<encpw>.*)/$','getimagecontent',name='getimagefile'),
)
```

My views.py contains:

```
def getimagecontent(request,extractedcontent_id,encpw):
........
```

And finally my template that's giving me the error contains the following line:

```
<li class="active"><img src="{% url getimagefile img,encpw %}" title=""/></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your encpw variable ends in a newline character, by default the . regular expression character does not capture these.  Try altering your regex so the DOTALL flag is turned on, which will match for newline characters.

```
url(r'(?s)^getimage/(?P<extractedcontent_id>\d+)/(?P<encpw>.*)/$','getimagecontent',name='getimagefile'),
```

Notice the `(?s)` at the very beginning this will turn the DOTALL flag on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show where `encpw` comes from, but it appears to have a newline character (`\n`) at the end, which won't match the url regex.